# Extracting multiple strings from a sentence that has been passed through the Stanford NER tagger

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I wrote code to extract multiple patterns from my string which has passed through a Stanford NER parser and gives output like:

```
Input Sentence - Goldman profit at risk under Volcker rule 
Output Sentence - Goldman profit at risk under <PERSON>Volcker</PERSON> rule
```

I need to extract the word Volker and put it in personTag map which eventually gets printed later in the code. The code below gives me a null pointer exception on list.add(m.group(1));

I am unable to figure out why. Please help with this.

```
    ..............

    HashMap<String, String> regs = new HashMap<String, String>();

    regs.put("PERSON", "<PERSON>(.+?)</PERSON>");
    regs.put("LOCATION", "<LOCATION>(.+?)</LOCATION>");
    regs.put("TIME", "<TIME>(.+?)</TIME>");
    regs.put("PERCENT", "<PERCENT>(.+?)</PERCENT>");
    regs.put("MONEY", "<MONEY>(.+?)</MONEY>");
    regs.put("DATE", "<DATE>(.+?)</DATE>");


for (Entry<String, String> entry : regs.entrySet()) 
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(value).matcher(NER);
    ArrayList<String> list = null;

    while (m.find())
    {
        if (key.contains("PERSON")){

            list.add(m.group(1));
            personTag.put(key, list);
            //System.out.println("Person Tag:" + personTag);
            roleStrings.put(SemanticRole.PERSON, personTag.toString());
        }
        else if (key.contains("LOCATION")){
            list.add(m.group());
            locationTag.put(key, list);
            roleStrings.put(SemanticRole.LOCATION, locationTag.toString());
        }
        else if (key.contains("TIME")){
            list.add(m.group(1));
            timeTag.put(key, list);
            roleStrings.put(SemanticRole.TIME, timeTag.toString());
        }
        else if (key.contains("DATE")){
            list.add(m.group(1));
            timeTag.put(key, list);
            roleStrings.put(SemanticRole.TIME, timeTag.toString());
        }
    }
}
return roleStrings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind that. I had not initialized my list hence was getting the null pointer exception. This is what I had to do:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Instead of:

```
 List<String> list = null;
```